# What is this thing that is falling off under my car

Tags: ford, focus

Noticed this bar falling off under my car. MPG appears to drop drastically. What is this thing?

2013 Ford Focus

[image]

Comment: Make, model and year of car?

Comment: @Moab Ford Focus 2013

Answer (score 1):

Bar to hold the undertray given the red plastic fixing close to the end.

Answer (score -2):

Just an undercarriage strap.  Keeps things from rattling a bit.  Not an essential component.

Comment: Yeah, Ford will spend money on a low end car for non essential components.